# Getting CP2K to print the COLVAR info

Tags: cp2k

Is it possible to make CP2K to print the values of all the defined COLVARs? I did find the following subsection in COLVAR section

```
  &COLVAR
    &DISTANCE
      ATOMS 50 52
    &END DISTANCE
    &PRINT
      &PROGRAM_RUN_INFO HIGH
        &EACH
          MD 1
          GEO_OPT 1
        &END EACH
        LOG_PRINT_KEY .TRUE.
        FILENAME colvar
      &END PROGRAM_RUN_INFO
    &END PRINT
  &END COLVAR
```

But that did not do anything. I have defined a COLVAR but I have not given a CONSTRAINT to it.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!

Comment: @NikeDattani I have absolutely no solution to it yet. For now, I wrote a Python script to calculate the Collective Variable. Which solves it for now. But for very large trajectories, it is always nice have CP2K print it as it would anyways be calculating it. Especially for Collective Variables like Coordination number.

Comment: Can you tell me where the collective variable is calculated in CP2K? I can try to get it printed for you.